# How to set time in query in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a query in which i want to select records for a single day only. like b/w '00:00:00' to '23:59:59'.

for example if user select data and time(2016-06-27 10:40) then my query would be like:

```
 select * from users where logtime between ? and '2016-06-27 23:59:59' // logtime is a timestamp
```

As per requirement on html page i only need to give an option that user can select a single date and time and then submit a search. I am confusing that in a sql query how i can append a end date(whatever date user select) and time(always be 23:59:59).
Can someone give me idea is there any postgres function which can help to extract a date from given date and append time(23:59:59) and return a datetime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract a date from a timestamp by simply casting the timestamp to `date`. So if I understand you problem correctly, you should something like that:

```
select * from users where logtime::date='2016-06-27 10:40'::date;
```

**Edit**: If you really want to simply extract the date to combine it with a different timestamp you can do it by manipulating the timestamp as a string, eg:

```
SELECT ('2016-06-27 10:40'::date || ' 23:59:59')::timestamp;
```

Comment: Ok if i am not wrong ::date would extract 2016-06-27 from user input value but ? and how i can add this date and set time(23:59:59) in other and clause of my query ?

Comment: I am sorry again, If you see my query again after where clause:   where logtime between '2016-06-27 10:40' and '2016-06-27 23:59:59'. I am using " between ' ' and ' '  " how this assignment can be work as you write a query. Can you please share a complete query

Comment: That's the point of my first query, you don't need the `BETWEEN` thing. It is easier to simply work with dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use berween clause, you can try this

```
select * from users where logtime between in_date::timestamp and 
    (in_date::date || ' 23:59:59')::timestamp; --in_date is input date from html page
```

you can refer [datetime in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) for more details and timestamp manipulation.

Hope it helps.